# Porque é que este código não dá erro, mas não retorna nada?

Tags: loop, haskell

Estou ainda a aprender Haskell (na verdade só comecei à cerca de 2 dias) com um conhecimento de C# básico.

Neste pedaço de código é suposto o código iterar várias vezes numa lista e subtraindo o primeiro valor ao segundo até terminar. O problema é que quando eu executo o código ele não dá erros, mas entra numa espécie de loop infinito, porque não acontece nada.

```
sub :: [Float] -> Float
sub [] = 0
sub (x : xs) = sub ( subtract (head xs) x : xs)
```

Também tentei este código, mas ele apenas subtrai os primeiros 2 valores da lista. Eu sei mais ou menos o porquê, mas não sei como resolver.

```
sub :: [Float] -> Float
sub [] = 0
sub (x : xs) = subtract (head xs) x
```

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

O principal ponto que faltou foi chamar novamente a função sub da forma correta. Não entendi muito bem o que você quer fazer, veja se a iteração abaixo é o resultado esperado:

```
Input: [1,2,3,4]

1. [1,2,3,4] -- (2 - 1) (2° posição - 1° posição)
2. [1,1,3,4] -- (3 - 1) (3° posição - 2° posição)
3. [1,1,2,4] -- (4 - 2) (4° posição - 3° posição)
4. [1,1,2,2] -- Final
```

Nesse caso estamos subtraindo a próxima posição pelo resultado já subtraído. Se for essa sua necessidade então o código é o seguinte:

```
sub :: [Int] -> [Int]
sub [] = []
sub (x:xs)
  | length xs == 0 = [x]
  | otherwise = [x] ++ sub ([y - x] ++ drop 1 xs)
  where y = head(xs)

main = do
  let list = [1,2,3,4]
  print $ sub list -- [1,1,2,2]
```

Estou usando Guards (Semelhante ao switch/case) que diz o que se a cauda for de tamanho 0 retorna o próprio valor (Isso é necessário pois head(xs) não pode receber uma lista vazia e também ajuda em listas com apenas 1 valor). Se a cauda da lista for maior que 0 eu concateno x e uso `sub` em uma nova lista que é a concatenação da subtração feita com a cauda menos 1 elemento à esquerda. É um pouco confuso mesmo mas vou fazer as iterações para ficar mais fácil:

```
Input: [1,2,3,4]

1. [1] ++ sub ([2 - 1, 3, 4])
2. [1] ++ sub ([3 - 1, 4])
3. [2] ++ sub ([4]) -- apenas 1 elemento retorna o elemento
4. [1,1,2,2] -- Final
```